# How to interpret permanova adonis output with fixed nested factors?

Tags: vegan

I am not quite sure how to interpret ":" in adonis2 output (vegan package) when using both nested factors and interactions.

For exemple, without nested factors :

```
        adonis_data <- adonis2(Y ~ 
                       A*B*C , data=factors, 
                       permutations = 9999, method = "euclidean")

        adonis_data
```

Interactions between factors are represented with ":" in the result output such as:

```
   Terms added sequentially (first to last)
        A       ***
        B       ***
        C       ***
        A:C     ***
        B:C     ***
```

However, when integrating a nested effect (either with ":" or "/") :

```
        adonis_data <- adonis2(Y ~ 
                       A:B*C , data=factors, 
                       permutations = 9999, method = "euclidean")

        adonis_data
```

I have difficulty to interpret this output as I don't know how nested factors are showed here (with or without ":")

```
   Terms added sequentially (first to last)
        A      ***
        C      ***
        A:B    ***
        A:C    ***
        A:C:B  ***
```

So here, I'm not quite sure if A:B is showing an effect of my nested factor rather than an interaction...

My last thought on the matter was that if nested factors are written as interactions in the output (e.g. A:B), we could differentiated both by the order of results considering that the terms are added sequentially.

So, if this is correct, that would mean that nested B should be between A and C and that A:B here is rather an interaction ?

Is it correct to conclude here that the B effect within A on Y is different according to A value ?

Does anyone can enlighten me ?
Many thanks,
Laura

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a general issue with **R** formula and in no way special to `adonis` or **vegan**. Anyway, in default `adonis2` (which currently is just `adonis`), the tests are sequential, and this really means that *previous* terms will influence the results, but later (subsequent) terms have no effect. What the terms are, depends on the way you define your model, like you demonstrated in you question.